# Passing parameters between Velocity templates

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to find out how to pass parameter while calling a velocity template from another.

it looks like this

File: _reading_tracker.vm

```
#parse("student/shared/_bio_data.vm")
```

I need to pass some arguments to the _bio_data.vm. Not sure how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of parsing `_bio_data.vm`, try [creating a macro, and then calling that macro](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html#Velocimacros) from `_reading_tracker.vm`.

Or, if you don't want to use a macro, then you should be able to `#set($var="value")` any number of variables in the outer template, and refer to those variables in the inner (parsed) template.

Comment: thank you...i was under assumption macros are meant only for common functions and should not contain html code